# Pygnuplot export to Excel chart

Tags: python, gnuplot

I have 7 arrays for Y data and 1 array for X data. I want to save them as columns in a table in Excel file along with a nice Excel multi-Y-axis chart embedded in there (similar as on the picture). Can I use directly **Pygnuplot** to export directly such a .xls file? How can I do that? I use Linux environment.[image]

Comment: @tom10, it was just for a clue how the attached plot was generated. Yeah, better delete it in order to not confuse participants.

Comment: Seems like a hard question...

Comment: The last one and this looks hard. I doubt it is possible at all and I need gnuplot guru.

Comment: Seems to me like void speaking... I just need expert opinion if gnuplot has out-of-the-box capabilities to export _excel_chart_ format in an _excel_ file. Nothing more. In order to know if it is not a waste to invest time in exploring it. What is not clear?

Comment: About the application of this - to generate an Excel file automatically for further analysis by anyone by just opening that file on any computer with Excel. Clicking the dots, seeing the values, modifying data, rechecking the plot l, etc. Is it clear now?

Comment: @tom10, please defend your statement why you have clicked (-1). This is a generic question about gnuplot capabilities in general I don't need code at that stage.

Comment: I downvoted this question because: 1) it's unclear; 2) you're asking people for information that you could easily search for; 3) when I tried to help you with it you became personally insulting; 4) you're looking for a tool/library and that's generally off-topic for SO; 5) it's not clear what you're looking for without reading the comments; 6) your statement, "if it is not a waste to invest time" seems overly concerned with your time and not the time of people trying to help. So I downvoted to suggest that I don't think this question is a net benefit.

Comment: If you rewrite it so it's clear, I'm happy to remove the downvote.  (And you are looking for a tool/library but I'm generally OK with that if it's [directed well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186245/a-borderline-between-on-topic-questions-and-questions-about-library-recommendati).)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out on how to write directly xls files yet.
In the meantime I can recommend using https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-insert-image

from gnuplot you can save the figure into a png file directly and then pass it into an Excel file.

```
from PyGnuplot import gp
import xlsxwriter
import numpy as np

fig1 = gp()
fig1.a('plot sin(x)')

# Tell gnuplot to output to a png
fig1.c('set terminal png size 400,300 enhanced font "Helvetica,20"')
fig1.c('set output "my_figure.png"')
fig1.a('replot')

# use xlsxwriter to add figure into an excel workbook
workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('my_file.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.insert_image('B2', 'my_figure.png')
workbook.close()
```